# Time series plot with more granularity at present time

Tags: time-series, time-varying-covariate, exploratory-data-analysis

How can i plot realtime timeseries data in a exponential interval.. I mean older data with less granular time scale and present data at higher granular time scale? Any inputs plz

Answer (score 1):

You could switch the x-axis (time since event) to logarithmic, and plot (current_time - observation_time).  This would have the effect you want, but current time would be at zero, with time moving from right to left.

If you wanted time to move from left to right, you would probably need a more complicated transformation of the data and/or axis.

What tools do you use to plot?

Comment: $-\log(t_{now}-t_{obs})$ as the horizontal axis to keep the "intuitive" orientation. And perhaps we may need to add a small constant to the logarithm to prevent $\log 0$.

Comment: I guess, strictly speaking, you shouldn't need to add a constant, since all observations are by definition some time in the past, even if only by a fraction of a second.  The question mentions 'realtime' data, but to have an exponential/log view, you would need to refresh the whole display every time you added a new observation, and by the time the plot was redrawn, the observation would inevitably be in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still exploring the options to plot the data. It's something like cpu utilization I am plotting.. I would be interested in recent past data with more granulartime axis value. Hope I am clear now